# Preset min/max values in symbology when importing a raster into QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have 200+ .tif files I need to import into QGIS and visually inspect. Due to the nature of the data, I need to manually set the min/max values to 0 and 0.8 , respectively. No matter what, the min/max values always need to be the same in order to view the data. Is there a way to automatically have QGIS import the rasters with those min/max values already set so I don't need to manually set each one in the symbology tab when added as a layer?

Comment: Once loaded, you can set the correct setting for one layer and than copy it's style to all other layers.

Comment: This is a useful way about it, that way you only have to define symbology parameters once. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can interpret your tasks as one of two things, however both use the same process.

1. Run reclassify by table as a batch process.
2. Give them all the same classification table. The table should be something like this:

If you are trying to set all values higher and lower to your min max, set it to something like this:

```
-999999 to 0 -> 0
0.8 to 9999999 -> 0.8
```

If you are trying to set all values out of your min max as no data, then set it to something like this:

```
-999999 to 0 -> -9999
0.8 to 9999999 -> -9999
```

You may have to play with some settings as I am not sure how your nodata values are set up. However this should generally give you the output that you are after.

Comment: This does work, thank you. I suppose I was finding a way to preset symbology conditions without needing to reclassify the actual data values, but this does meet my needs. Babel's comment to my original post is also helpful, where you set the symbology once, copy those settings, then select all layers and paste those settings.